# How do I GetLength() of three dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I try this:

```
float[, ,] arrays = new float[,,] { 
    { 
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 }         
    }

    {
        { 7, 8, 9 },
        { 10, 11, 12 },
        { 13, 14, 15 }  
    }       
};

void Start() {

    print(arrays[0].GetLength);

}
```

I get this: 'System.Single' does not contain a definition for 'GetLength'

I want to know, how many rows has arrays[0] or arrays[1] etc.

I don't want use lists.

EDIT:
I have it now.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

```
int[][,] jaggedArray4 = new int[3][,] 
{
    new int[,] { {1,3}, {5,7} },
    new int[,] { {0,2}, {4,6}, {8,10} },
    new int[,] { {11,22}, {99,88}, {0,9} } 
};
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "I want to know, how many rows has arrays[0] or arrays[1] etc."

Comment: Now in this array, there are 2 array packages. 1-6 and 7-15. 1-6 has two rows and 7-15 has 3 rows. How can I get this rows?

Comment: No, there really aren't. It sounds like you might want a `float[][,]` or a `float[,][]`. What you've currently got is a cube of floats, effectively.

Comment: Can you give me an example for float[][,] please? Your solution sounds good.

Comment: Not really - not without more information about what you're trying to achieve. It wouldn't be an answer to *this question* for one thing. I suggest you ask a new question with more context.

Comment: What must I search for when I want to make it like this: float[][,]?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "what must I search for" - search for in order to do what? Have you *tried* anything yet? See what you can do, and if you don't succeed, ask a new question with more context. We still don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Now I have it. Please look question. Thank you Jon. I found a solution, because of this here: float[][,]

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`GetLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx) method and specify the dimension for which you want to get the length:

```
arrays.GetLength(0);
```

or if you wanted to get the length of the second dimension:

```
arrays.GetLength(1)
```

and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

`arrays[0]` is an invalid expression since you are missing two indexes. In the error message the compiler seems to treat this expression as a `float`. You can't call array methods on a float. That's where the error seems to come from. Correct the indexing expression and call the array methods on `array`.

Maybe you confuse multi-dimensional arrays and jagged arrays. Jagged arrays contain sub-arrays that are themselves objects.

Comment: `arrays[0]` is simply an invalid expression - `arrays[0,0,0]` would be a `float`, but `arrays[0]` isn't anything...

Comment: I think this is not the real code. It shouldn't compile.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. His code does not compile as a fact.

Comment: I mean it should fail earlier before giving this error message

Comment: What do mean by "earlier"? Compilation is not sequential line-by-line. There is no notion of time. This code never runs.